# XMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement(prefix,localName,namespaceURI), Prefix "manifest" can not be resolved to namespace URI

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces

`source.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zip:archive xmlns:manifest="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:manifest:1.0" xmlns:zip="com.test.zip">
<zip:entry zip:target="test1.xml"><manifest:manifest>aaa</manifest:manifest></zip:entry>
<zip:entry zip:target="test2.xml">.......</zip:entry>
</zip:archive>
```

I use `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader` to read `source.xml` file, do some action, and then write to disk according to the attribute value of `zip:target`.

the result file, test1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest:manifest>aaa</manifest:manifest>
```

You know, it is wrong. Prefix "manifest" can not be resolved to namespace URI.

Through the debugging, I found the following statement was successfully called.

```
XMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement("manifest", "manifest", "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:manifest:1.0");
```

The third parameter of writeStartElement is not null. But why is the namespace missing in the result file?

I tried two methods:

1. set sRepairingNamespaces to be true
2. add writeNamespace after writeStartElement

But new trouble come, the namespaces were redeclared and duplicate.

Comment: If setting sRepairingNamespaces to be true, new trouble come, the namespaces were redeclared and duplicate.

Comment: Have you provided an implementation of `NamespaceContext` to the `XMLStreamWrite`r to bind URIs to prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to setPrefix before writeStartElement.  I don't think you'll need sRepairingNamespaces - but I'm not sure.

Comment: It doesn't work! The special of this question: dividing a xml file to several xml files, and the namespaces are in the root node.